# Load my partial view in a specific div at the same page after a click

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this code

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult ManageEmployee(int cntID, string command)
{
    repository = new ContactRepository();
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(command) && command.Equals("edit"))
    {
        LKIContact employees = repository.GetById(cntID);

        ViewBag.IsUpdate = true;
        return PartialView("_ManageEmployee", employees);
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.IsUpdate = false;
        return PartialView("_ManageEmployee");
    }
}
```

When I click on :

```
<a href='Home/ManageEmployee?cntID=${cntID}&command=edit' class='editDialog'>Edit</a>
```

I execute the first part of the above method to display my populated form for update
when I click on `href='Home/ManageEmployee?cntID=0&command=create' class='openDialog'` I open the empty form to add a new employee.

My problem now is that when I click on edit or create I have the desired result but in another page. What I want is to slide out those forms in the specific divs (below) while staying at the same page.(under the grid)

```
<div id="dialog-edit"></div>
<div id="dialog-create" style="display: none"></div>
```

here is the code where my grid will be loaded and the location of the divs where I want my forms to be loaded

```
@section featured {
<section class="featured">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- the igHierarchicalGrid target element-->
        <table id="employeeGrid" style="width: auto;"></table>
        <p>
            <!--<a id='openDialog' href='Home/CreateEmployee?cntID=0' class='openDialog ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only' style="color: white;"><button>Add Employee</button></a>-->
       </p>
    </div>
</section>

<br />
<div id="dialog-confirm" style="display: none">
    <p>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>
            Are you sure to delete ?
    </p>
</div>

<div id="dialog-edit"></div>

<div id="dialog-view" style="display: none"></div>

}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Check out http://api.jquery.com/load/ for getting HTML from the server and stuffing that into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax call to get partial view and render it in your div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on("click", "#btnEdit", function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: "Home/ManageEmployee?cntID=" + myEmployeeID + "&command=edit";
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $("#dialog-edit").append(html);
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Add this script at the bottom of your page, replace `btnEdit` with the id of your edit button and replace the `MyEmployeeID` with the employeeid you want to edit.

Comment: You mentioned that every row of grid had edit button. Can you post the markup for grid? You can edit your question and append code to it.

Comment: Sorry, my answer wouldn't help much for igGrid.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an edit button for each row, you would include the EmployeeId within the link tag, perhaps as a data attribute so

```
<a href='Home/ManageEmployee?cntID=${cntID}&command=edit' data-employeeid='${cntID}' class='editor'><button>Edit</botton></a>
```

Then using the example from afzalulh just pick up on the data attribute

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on("click", ".editor", function () {

        var myEmployeeID = $(this).data('employeeid');

        $.ajax({
            url: "Home/ManageEmployee?cntID=" + myEmployeeID + "&command=edit";
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $("#dialog-edit").append(html);
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for your help but unfortunately didn't get the result needed